# Why media library breaks after I delete a component, a single type or a collection type in Strapi?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

Problem:
Deleting a component in Strapi breaks the media library.
Deleting a collection/single type in Strapi the Media Library brokes.

Technical Stack: MongoDB and Strapi

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a picture in the media library in Strapi, and afterward you reference it on components or page, a relation is created between that component/page and your picture. In MongoDb in the upload_file collection, you'll have all your picture objects. On each object, you'll have a property named 'related'. [image]

The problem appears when you delete a component or page which is referenced into that array. If you delete the component or page and the reference exists the media library picture object, will break.
You'll have to go into the database, open the upload_file collection, check every object, and delete the reference from the array.
Don't delete all the elements from the array only the ones which you don't need.